# Apache Spark WordCount method not sorting Data

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
 def wordCount(dataSet: RDD[String]): Map[String, Int] = {
    val counts = dataSet.flatMap(line => line.split(","))
        .map(word => (word, 1))
        .reduceByKey(_ + _)
        .sortBy(_._2, ascending = false)
        counts.collectAsMap()  
 }
```

This Method is not sorting the final result as aspected

`.sortBy(_._2, ascending = false)`

the output of this method will be in descending order but the output is still the random
any reason or solution?

Comment: Maps are not ordered/sorted. Use collect instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method collectAsMap() internally creates a HashMap of values which in this case not ordered. Use collect or takeOrdered for sorted values.